# Arithmetic addition to aggregate function

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql and wanted to perform a simple task using aggregate function in sql.

```
select  (current_data + avg(current_data)) 
as "average + current data"
from datasets
```

However, arithmetic addition to aggregate function seems to not work in sql.
What should I do to add current_data to the value of avg(current_data)?

Comment: Which row's `current_data` is supposed to be added to the average of all the row's `current_data` values? Note that a constant like `SELECT 1 + avg(current_data) FROM datasets` will work.

Comment: @Shawn I'm trying to perform (current_data + avg(current_data)) for all of the rows that i have. For example, if i have a dataset containing 1 to 10 for each row, the avg(current_data) becomes 5.5, and want to add each row of data (1,2,.....10) to 5.5, so in the output it shows (6.5, 7.5,......15.5) for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty this-

```
SELECT current_data + 
(
    SELECT avg(current_data) FROM datasets
) AS 'average + current data'
FROM datasets
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid calculation of average for every row, I would suggest to calculate average first and then use it.

```
DECLARE @avg INT
SET @avg = (SELECT AVG(current_data) FROM dataset)

SELECT current_data + @avg
FROM dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to perform (current_data + avg(current_data)) for all of the rows that i have. For example, if i have a dataset containing 1 to 10 for each row, the avg(current_data) becomes 5.5, and want to add each row of data (1,2,.....10) to 5.5, so in the output it shows (6.5, 7.5,......15.5) for each row

For that, you want the version of `avg()` that is a *window function*, indicated as such by the `OVER` keyword (Available in many, but not all, databases):

```
SELECT current_data + avg(current_data) OVER () AS "average + current_data"
FROM datasets
ORDER BY current_data;
```

gives

```
average + current_data
----------------------
6.5                   
7.5                   
8.5                   
9.5                   
10.5                  
11.5                  
12.5                  
13.5                  
14.5                  
15.5
```